# Is it possible to query wagtail using a value of an orderable field

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a wagtail page with an orderable field, however, I need to query from the API based on the value of an orderable. So for example, a manufacturer page has a field for products, which is a one to many relationship, and I want to get all manufacturers that make a particular product using the API

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the `related_name` on the ParentalKey, you're setting up a relation that you can query using [Django query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). For your example, if your orderable's ParentalKey has `related_name='products`, this would be something like:

```
ManufacturerPage.objects.filter(products__name='teapot')
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but I mean from the REST API. I can only do things like 

`?type=manufacturers.Manufacturer&slug=big-page` 

but not something like 

`?type=manufacturers.Manufacturer&products.id=3`